# Ejecutar sentencias SQL en Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Me gustaría ejecutar sentencias SQL en un dataframe obtenido a partir de un archivo CSV, estoy creando un programa con uso de comandos con la librería Click en Python y quiero usar sentencias SQL para filtrar datos en un dataframe sin tener que conectarme a una base de datos, todo en local y a partir de un dataframe obtenido por un archivo CSV, ¿alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/

Comment: Pandasql solo sirve para hacer Selects creo, hay alguna otra librería que te permita por ejemplo hacer DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT, etc... con el dataframe de pandas?